# how to achieve this effect with css html?

Tags: html, css, image

Could any of you guys tell me how to achieve this image effect with the image being displayed slightly out of its div(in green)??

I am not sure what is this effect called therefore I was unable to use google to search for this.

how do I make this image slightly out of it's box??
here's the link to the image [image: image effect]

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>practice site 2</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Fontawesome library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice2.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

<div class="first">
<p>CONVERSIFIC</p>
<p><span class="span1">The 1st</span><br>Business Intelligence Platform<br><span class="span2">for Shopify</span></p>
<p>We show you how to grow your revenue<br><span class="span3">-all you have to do is take action</span></p>

<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter your email" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Add me to Beta">
    </form>
    <p>Join our beta today,be the first to get access to Conversific</p>

</div><!--first div ends -->

<div class="use">
<h1>Why use Conversicif?</h1>
<hr class="firsth">

<div class="box row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="graph.jpg" alt="graph">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p><strong>Conversific helps you make intelligent decisions to grow your business</strong></p>  
    <p>There are plentfy of platforms that make it easy to capture data and analytics about your ecommerce site.But when it comes to understanding the data you've captured, it's not always clear what's important and where to make changes.</p>
    </div>

</div><!--box div ends -->
<div class="positions">
<h1>How does Conversific work?</h1>
<p>Say goodbye to gathering reports and analyzing data and head straight to decision making </p>
<hr class="second">
<div class="threebox row">
<div class="col-lg-4"><p>Conversific is installed onto your ecommerce store with just one click from your shopify store</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"><p>After the installation you just need to install google analytics</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"><p>Immediately after you have signed in you see a comprehensive reports overview</p></div>


</div><!--threebox row ends -->
</div><!-- positions div ends-->
</div><!--use div ends -->




<div class="features">
<h1> Features you'll love</h1>
<p>These are the features you are going to love no matter what<br>
    So, is this the end of the paragraph or what or are you gonna keep<br>
    typing till your fingers bleed??</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
<p>ECOMMERCE FOCUS<br><span class="spanf">Decision Focused Dashboards To<br> Supercharge Your Ecommerce Business</span><br>
There are plenty of platforms that make it easy to capture data and analytics about your ecommerce site. But when it comes to understanding the data you've captured. It's not always clear what's important and where to make changes.<br>
    <button>Join Now</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">

    </div>

</div><!-- row ends -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"><p>EASY TO UNDERSTAND<br><span class="spanf">Optimize Your Product & Category<br> Performance</span><br>
There are plenty of platforms that make it easy to capture data and analytics about your ecommerce site. But when it comes to understanding the data you've captured. It's not always clear what's important and where to make changes.<br>
    <button>Join Now</button></p></div>

</div><!-- row ends -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"><p>INCREASE REVENUE<br><span class="spanf">Turbo Boost Your marketing and Find<br> Top Performing Marketing Channels</span><br>
See which marketing channels are the most effective for your business<br>and maximize your return on investment<br>
    <button>Join Now</button></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>

</div><!-- row ends -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"><p>ECOMMERCE FOCUS<br><span class="spanf">Decision Focused Dashboards To<br> Supercharge Your Ecommerce Business</span><br>
There are plenty of platforms that make it easy to capture data and analytics about your ecommerce site. But when it comes to understanding the data you've captured. It's not always clear what's important and where to make changes.<br>
    <button>Join Now</button></p></div>

</div><!-- row ends -->

</div><!-- features div ends -->
<div class="pillars"></div>
<div class="team"></div>
<div class="end"></div>

</div><!-- container div ends -->




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: open new `pen` in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/)

Comment: ok, here's the link to codepen - http://codepen.io/silentarrowz/pen/zKYRjv

Comment: I want the image to come out just a wee bit from the border, in the same way as the image shown here.
the image is shifted to the right from it's containing box, then one with the green border ( as shown in the image in original post.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]its quite easy ! here the tricks . on hover it will slightly out of it's box as picture shows

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#box{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
margin-top:-100px;
}
#box:hover{

      margin-left:10px;
      margin-top:-110px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:black;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
<div id="box"></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your codepen you probably want to fix the width and height of your container but that is up to you, what will I than do is

```
// col-lg-6 or whatever is the container of the image
.col-lg-6 {
    padding: 10px;
}
// play around with the value to achieve the right spacing
.img-responsive {
    margin: -20px -20px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`.img-responsive {
    width : 100%;
}`

Bootstrap's responsive image class sets max-width to 100%. This limits its size, but does not force it to stretch to fill parent elements larger than the image itself. You'd have to use the width attribute to force upscaling.

Comment: that doesnt make any difference at all. it's still inside the div.

Comment: check your parent div `padding` with right-click and `inspect` in chrome brwoser